# Фильтрованный поиск по товару

Tags: mysql, php, eav

Здравствуйте есть таблицы

```
attributes: id, title
'1', 'Мониторы'
'2', 'Процессор'

values: id, value
'1', '1920x900'
'2', 'core i5'

attribute_to_value: attribute_id, value_id
'1', '1'
'2', '2'

products_attribute_value: product_id, value_id, attribute_id
'1', '1', '1'
'1', '2', '2'

products: id, title

'1', 'Компьютер номер №1'
'2', 'Компьютер номер №2'
'3', 'Компьютер номер №3'
```

Помогите составить запрос и выбрать товар по следущим критериям монитор=1920х900 и процессор=core i5, мучаюсь уже много дней.

Замечу что критерий может быть множество, 1-10 и больше.

Comment: Для чего нужна таблица `attribute_to_value`, если она дублируется в `products_attribute_value`?

Comment: Структуру БД создавал не я, мне тоже показалось что таблица attribute_to_value лишняя, но Автор зачем то её создал, значит пусть будет, хоть и вряд ли пригодиться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется паттерн [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model), да уже увидел тэг соответствующий.

Назначение таблицы `attribute_to_value` в том, чтобы перечислить все возможные значения для каждого атрибута. В частности это может быть использовано при редактировании товара: выпадающий список со значениями, которые может принимать данный параметр. А также эта таблица нужна для построения фильтра, из которой также берутся данные для выпадающего списка (или списка мультивыбора).

Запрос по товарам для такой структуры строится циклом по всем атрибутам. Чтобы вывести в таблице все товары со всеми заполненными свойствами будет выглядеть так:

```
select p.id, p.title, 
  v1.id as v1_id, v1.value as 'Мониторы',
  v2.id as v2_id, v2.value as 'Процессор'
from products p
  left join products_attribute_value pav1 on      
      p.id=pav1.product_id and pav1.attribute_id=1
    left join `values` v1 on pav1.value_id = v1.id
  left join products_attribute_value pav2 on 
      p.id=pav2.product_id and pav2.attribute_id=2
    left join `values` v2 on pav2.value_id = v2.id
```

и т.д.

Т.е. берем таблицу `attributes`, получаем из нее id и наименование, дальше подставляем их в соответствующие места запроса.

Таким образом мы получим таблицу товаров со всеми значениями параметров.

При построении данного запроса в отдельных случаях вы можете учесть:

- нужны ли вам значения атрибутов выборке, или достаточно только id товаров
- нужен ли вообще комплект join'ов, например, по количеству сим-карт из мобильных телефонов в группе по компьютерам
- будете ли вы фильтровать по значениям атрибутов или по их id (т.е. что будете искать "core i5" или 2)

в каждом из случаев можно будет опустить лишние данные...

Теперь. Как же фильтровать? Ну просто добавляете выражение where:

```
...
where
  v1.value = 'core i5'
  and v2.value = '1920x900'
```

Условия при этом могут естественно быть любыми, например >, <, between, in, like и т.д. Количество, участвующих фильтров также может быть произвольным, ясное дело.

Что со скоростью? Все верно, много join'ов, надо быть предельно аккуратным с индексами. Если у вас будет хоть намек на выборку без индекса, получите тормоза. Поэтому для `products_attribute_value` нужен составной индекс по всем трем полям. Он скорее всего будет уникальным, если у вас нет множественных значений для свойств (для множественных значений нужно будет еще одно - инкрементное - поле).

Вот вам примеры запросов [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdaec1/1) (Спасибо [[@ua6xh](/users/14126/ua6xh)](/users/14126/ua6xh) за схему), обратите внимание на добавленный индекс по `products_attribute_value`. Там еще добавлено по join'у для названий атрибутов, их также можно опустить если они не нужны. А нужны они могут быть для того, чтоб в коде получить значение свойства по его индексу

```
echo $res[$res["attr".$i."_name"]]; // значение для свойства с номером `$i`, это будет поле `Мониторы` и значение `'1920x900'`
```

либо как вариант, не использовать русские имена (например) в псевдонимах колонок, но тогда при отстраивании таблицы также надо будет получать соответствие названия колонки и id атрибута.

Скорее всего ваш запрос будет выглядеть по-другому, и это правильно. Тут приведены варианты для наглядности. Важно то, что если вы посмотрите план запроса, то все связи идут через индексы, многие через первичные, это гарантирует приемлемую скорость.

**N.B.** При достаточно интенсивных обращениях к базе такие запросы также могут ее подвесить (ничего в этом удивительного или страшного). поэтому стоит позаботиться о кэшировании (начинать можно [отсюда](http://habrahabr.ru/post/108274/)). В этом случае вам крайне редко вообще придется беспокоиться о скорости выполнения таких запросов, пусть даже на большой базе товаров они и будут занимать пару секунд (все зависит от объемов номенклатуры).

Comment: поиск по двум параметрам уже 4 join'a, а если параметров 10? значит 20 join'ов, Проверить скорость смогу только дома, а вы как считаете это не сильно медленно получится? я честно не знаю :)

Comment: например, можете пройтись по этим сайтам http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/cms/projects/

Comment: По вашему вот это http://euroset.ru/catalog/phones/mobile/ Реализовано так же?

Comment: именно. в битриксе используется eav, все остальные сайты по ссылке выше также работают на аналогичных запросах.

Answer (score 3):

Пока есть только такой вариант:

```
SELECT p.* FROM products_attribute_value a JOIN products_attribute_value b ON a.product_id = b.product_id 
JOIN products p ON p.id = a.product_id WHERE
a.attribute_id = 1 AND a.value_id = 1 AND b.attribute_id = 2 AND b.value_id = 2;
```

Но запрос плохой, первое что в голову пришло. Каждое новое условие будет добавлять новый джоин...

Код на [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3b1e/3)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но конечно же у меня не будет осуществлятся поиск всего по двум параметрам : ) в результате получится слишком много Join'ов - не лучшее решение.

Comment: > слишком много Join'ов - не лучшее решение

кто сказал?

Comment: Не ужели запрос с 10 join'ами будет лучшим решением для данной задачи? :)

Comment: а вы в яндекс маркет загляните, врядли там при каждом добавлении нового свойства проводят реструктуризацию всей базы с товарами. даунтайм я так предполагаю был бы не меньше суток...