# EAV — как сделать структуру более универсальной и легкой?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, архитектура, eav

Возникла задача реализовать мини-интернет-магазин. Особенность - атрибуты товаров динамичны, т.е. может продаваться как крыло от боинга, так и сланцы. И сайт должен быть сделан и отдан, никакой тех.поддержки.

С такими условиями при построении модели *БД* была выбрана модель *EAV* как наиболее универсальная. Построил стандартную модель, вот как выглядит:

```
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for attributevalue
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attributevalue`;
CREATE TABLE `attributevalue` (
  `attribute_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `attribute_value` text,
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `productentity` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for productattribute
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `productattribute`;
CREATE TABLE `productattribute` (
  `attribute_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `attribute_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `product_id_attr` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_id_attr` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `productentity` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for productentity
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `productentity`;
CREATE TABLE `productentity` (
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Но, помимо вывода самих атрибутов, нужно реализовать поиск по ним.

Например, разделить атрибуты на группы, и назначать тип фильтра (*чекбокс*, диапазон, выпадающий список).

Как это лучше сделать? А то не хочется изобретать велосипед в век полетов в космос...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Список свойств должен быть единый на весь каталог: `attributes`.
- Для каждого атрибута указывается его тип (чекбоксы, диапазоны и т.д.).
- Каталог разбивается на группы `product_groups`, т.е. каждый товар в отдельной группе.
- Для каждой группы указывается список свойств `group_attributes` (то, что у вас для товаров в `productattribute`, должно быть для групп).
- Получаете описание свойств для товаров группы, выводите соответствующие виджеты фильтрации.
- Строите запрос для фильтра [см. здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264319/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83), и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/147160/mysql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-3-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Список свойств для групп является необязательным с точки зрения фильтра, т.е. список свойств можно получить через `select distinct attribute_id...` по товарам в группе, однако может пригодится при заполнении свойств для новых товаров. Данный список не является обязательным для всех товаров в группе, какие-то свойства у отдельных товаров могут отсутствовать.

Значения для выпадающих списков в фильтре, мин-макс значения и т.д. получаются агрегацией по `attributevalue`, впрочем опять же эти данные можно хранить в отдельных таблицах и или в кэше.

Наличие групп позволяет сделать иерархический каталог, сделать принадлежность товаров нескольким группам (дополнительной развязочной таблицей), сделать весь каталог в одной группе, все как душа пожелает, при этом у каждой группы будет свой набор свойств...